# Retrieving parent and child in transitive SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki, transitive-closure

I am looking for a way to return both the parent and child in a transitive SPARQL query, and only the relations that make up the path.

The following query returns the parents and intermediate object pairs leading up to http://example.com/child, but if any of the ?parents have other containment statements then those are returned as well.  This can make for a very large result set.

```
PREFIX  ex:   <http://example.com/>

SELECT ?parent ?child
WHERE {
    ?parent ex:contains+ <http://example.com/child> .
    ?parent ex:contains ?child
}
```

Is there a way to both bind the terminal object in a transitive query to a specific resource, and also return the object in each relation, but not all the other ex:contains relations for each parent?

For example, with the following graph:

```
ex:root ex:contains ex:rootchild1
ex:root ex:contains ex:rootchild2
ex:rootchild1 ex:contains ex:intermed
ex:intermed ex:contains ex:child
```

The result would be:

```
ex:root ex:rootchild1
ex:rootchild1 ex:intermed
ex:intermed ex:child
```

I am running this query with Jena and Fuseki.  Thanks!